# URL ignore after a certain parameter

Tags: url, iframe, hyperlink, url-parameters

A user can embed a YouTube URL in the application.  However the application is adding another question mark in the form of "?wmode=transparent" to the end of the URL.  This is a problem because the URL already includes "?rel=0" at the end of it.  rel=0 means to not show relative videos.

A url that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/embed/FV0-RQnfSwY?rel=0
```

Turns into this:

```
https://example.com/embed/FV0-RQnfSwY?rel=0?wmode=transparent.
```

And that breaks the rel=0 parameter.

Is there anything that can be added to the URL to signify the end of the parameters and everything after that point should be ignored?

The ability to remove ?wmode=transparent is not possible at this point.

Comment: Can you try adding a `&` after `rel=0`? So: `/embed/FV0-RQnfSwY?rel=0&?wmode=transparent`.

Comment: Good idea.  I tried it out but it did not work.